# If a set $E\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ is closed and open, then it is either $\Bbb{R}^n$ or $\emptyset$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, metric-spaces

If a set $E\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ is closed and open, then it is either $\Bbb{R}^n$ or $\emptyset$. I have an attempt. I know, or at least think, that it is correct **ideally**, but I don't know how to make it formal:

Suppose there is a set $A$ which is open and close(closed? I am not sure. It is translated). Suppose it isn't $\emptyset$. Let us look at the following sets: $int(A):=\{x\in A :\exists r_0\space \text{s.t}\space B(x,r_0)\subset A\}$, $\overline A:=\{x\in A :\exists x_n\space \text{s.t}\space x_n\to x\}$, and $\partial A=\overline A \setminus int (A)$. Let $x\in \partial A$. There is a sequence $x_n\subset A$ that converges to $x$, and since $A$ is close, then $x\in A$. Since $A$ is open, there exists $r_0$ such that $B(x,r_0)\subset A$, but that would mean that $x\in int(A)$, leading to a contradiction. Any guiding as for how to do it right is welcome.

Comment: You proved that $\partial A = \emptyset$. You need to show this implies that $A = \mathbb R^n$

Comment: So this is probably where I am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* If $E$ is clopen (=closed and open) then so is $\mathbb R^n\setminus E$. If either of these two is empty you are done. If not, consider a line segment with points in $E$ and $\mathbb R^n\setminus E$ as end points. We may identify this with $[0,1]$ and look at $\inf$ and $\sup$ of suitable sets.